# How to show a drop down menu from the collapse btn (bootstrap)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code for a bootstrap navbar and I added the collapse feature so whenever you have a small screen it collapses the the page links into button and whenever you push the btn it opens a drop down menu but I have a problem when clicking the collapse `btn` nothing happens please help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initialscale=1">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
      .box {
        border: 1px solid grey;
        background-color: #d3d3d3;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="" class="navbar-brand">My Website</a>
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" datatoggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Page 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are using jquery 1.11 and then jquery 3 and then bootstrap (without version, so we don't really know which version you use there). Something isn't right there :)

Comment: bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: And why use two version of jquery? And did you get any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: I have edited the code and removed the older version of jquery 1.11 but still nothing happens and their is an error in console :The key "initialscale" is not recognized and ignored.

Comment: You have `datatoggle="collapse"`, it should be `data-toggle="collapse"` with a hyphen. See [Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Comment: yes thank you that worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that you are missing **-** (**hypen**) in your **data-toggle** attribute

**use:**

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
data-target="#myNavbar">
```

**instead of:**

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" datatoggle="collapse"
data-target="#myNavbar">
```

> **Note:** You must include **jquery.js** & **bootstrap.js** (located in **js** folder) files to use this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using correct bootstrap libararies. I don't find anything wrong in your code. So I would suggest two alternative to you---
 1. Use these `CDN` s and in this perticular order.

**suggested**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

2. Change this two lines---

   ```
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
   data-target="#myNavbar">

   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
   ```

Hope this helps!